# Unable to locate package nvidia-settings-319

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, bumblebee

I have been trying to set up Bumblebee on Ubuntu 15.04 and I am having trouble installing the nvidia driver for it.

After I type:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319
```

I get the error: unable to locate package nvidia-settings-319.

Does anyone know what my problem may be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nvidia-319` is in the Ubuntu Restricted repository and available for all currently supported Ubuntu versions (12.04, 14.04, 15.04 and also 15.10), therefore

```
sudo apt-add-repository restricted
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319
```

`nvidia-settings` will be installed automatically.

At the end you have version 340.93 installed, because

[nvidia-319](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-319) depends on [nvidia-331](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-331) depends on [nvidia-340](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-340)

Comment: Thank you! I have Bumblebee installed but when I  try optirun glx gears I get an error [  341.315388] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[  341.315452] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?

Comment: Sorry, but that's a completely different question, therefore all a new one. And if the answer for your question is correct, you should accept the answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer. **;)**